# How to reach derived class variable from base class vector?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Entity
{
public:
    bool hinders_sight = false;
};

class Pillar : public Entity
{
public:
    bool hinders_sight = true;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Entity*> Entities;

    Pillar pillar;

    Entities.push_back(&pillar);

    std::cout << pillar.hinders_sight << std::endl;
    std::cout << Entities[0]->hinders_sight << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`pillar.hinders_sight` returns `true` (as it should)

but

`Entities[0]->hinders_sight` returns `false`.

How can I reach `hinders_sight` of `pillar` from the `vector`?

Comment: Variables are not virtual.You will need to make a virtual function accessing the variable.  Also it is confusing to use the same name for two different variables in the class. Maybe what you want to do here is to have Pillar's constructor set Entity::hinders_sight to true, instead of declaring another variable?

Comment: @M.M Out of curiosity what is wrong with using a `static_cast`, like this: `static_cast<Pillar*>(Entities[0])->hinders_sight`

Comment: @Jonas What if Entities[0] wasn't a Pillar? I imagine OP intends to expand this program into something where Entities can contain objects of various other types derived from Entity

Comment: @M.M Good point, and a virtual function is the way I'd do it. Any thoughts on using a `dynamic_cast`  as suggested in answer by lars?

Comment: @Jonas Yeah it would fail to compile. dynamic_cast can only be used on polymorphic classes. And it's going to lead to extremely awful code when there are several types to test.

Comment: @M.M Well, I suppose that could be fixed by adding a virtual destructor to `Entity`. Any issues besides that?

Comment: @Jonas down-casting is almost always a sign of bad design. If you use polymorphism, you shouldn't have to know the real type of the object.

Comment: @nefas We can agree on that immediately! I was just curious if this could be so bad a design that it might result in unforeseen errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `virtual bool HindersSight(){return hinders_sight;}` as variables are not virtual.

Edit: Oh and make your variables protected or private to promote encapsulation. You could complete get rid of the variable and implement HindersSight() for each class to directly return true or false.

Answer (score 3):

What is happening right now is that there are two variables called `hinders_sight` in your derived class, one from the base class and another of the derived class.

There are two main approaches to solve this problem here (I would not recommend keeping two separate variables for the same thing in your base and derived classes), either you can make the variable a protected/private variable in the base class and then offer functions to get and store the variable as needed, or you can make the `get_hinders_sight()` function virtual.

```
class Entity {
public:
    Entity(bool hinders_sight_in = false) 
        : hinders_sight{hinders_sight_in} {}
    bool get_hinders_sight() { return this->hinders_sight; }
private:
    bool hinders_sight = false;
};

class Pillar : public Entity {
public:
    Pillar() : Entity{true} {}
};
```

Or

```
class Entity {
public:
    virtual bool get_hinders_sight() { return false; }
};

class Pillar : public Entity {
public:
    bool get_hinders_sight() override { return true; }
};
```